# Prove $\exists\delta>0\ni\forall f\in C([0,1])$ with sup $|f|<\delta\ \exists g\in C^1([0,1])$ such that $g'+g^{30}=f$ (Use Implicit function theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

> Using Implicit function theorem show that that there exists $\delta>0$ such that
>  For all $f\in C([0,1];\Bbb{R})$ with $\text{sup }|f|<\delta,\ \exists g\in C^1([0,1];\Bbb{R})$ such that $$g'(t)+g(t)^{30}=f(t)$$

Although I feel like it as a differential equation $\displaystyle{\frac{dy}{dt}+y^{32}=f(t)}$. But I'm not getting any idea how to apply Implicit Function Theorem to get a $\delta>0$. Can anyone give any idea or way out to start with? Thanks for help in advance.

**Edit:** Later I have thought one way out

Define $T:C([0,1])\times C^1([0,1])\to C^1([0,1])$ by $T(f,g)(s)=g(s)-g(0)+\int\limits_0^s (g^{30}-f)$. Then $T(0,0)=0$, so we have to apply implicit function theorem to this $T$. Here I have taken sup norm for $C([0,1])$ and the $C^1$ norm (defined as $\lVert f\rVert_{C^1}=\text{sup }|f|+\text{sup }|f'|$) with respect to which $C^1$ is banach space (complete). Is it okay?

Comment: Qualitatively this means that there exists some radius $\delta > 0$ such that for all $f \in B(0,\delta)$, a certain equation involving $f$ admits at least a solution in $C^1$. It seems like we should study the regularity of the operator giving the equation and apply the implicit function theorem to this operator.

Comment: So I define $T:C([0,1])\times C^1([0,1])\to C^1([0,1])$ by $T(f,g)(s)=g(s)-g(0)+\int\limits_0^s (g^{30}-f)$. Then $T(0,0)=0$, so we have to apply implicit function theorem to this $T$, is it okay? Here I have taken sup norm for $C([0,1])$ and the $C^1$ norm (defined as $\lVert f\rVert_{C^1}=\text{sup }|f|+\text{sup }|f'|$) with respect to which $C^1$ is banach space (complete).

Comment: I guess it would work but you can study $T(f,g) = g' + g^{30} -f$ that seems more simple.

Comment: As per your construction the domain is $C([0,1])\times C^1([0,1])$. Now  to apply IMplicit, the range should be $C^1$. But $g'$ may not be a $C^1$ map.

Comment: The operator $D : g \in C^1 \longmapsto g' \in C^0$ is linear and note that $$  ||D(g)||_{C^0} = ||g'||_{C^0} \leq ||g'||_{C^0} + ||g||_{C^0} = ||g||_{C^1} $$ so it is a $1$-Lip operator. Thus it is linear continuous, $C^{\infty}$.